# Entity Framework Core 6 Migration Bundle Execution Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use the new EF Core migration bundle to update my database schema.

I have created the bundle using:

```
dotnet ef migrations bundle --self-contained --runtime linux-x64
```

But when I tried to update the database using:

```
./efbundle --connectionString ${MY_CONNETION_STRING}
```

Or even getting help by:

```
./efbundle --help
```

I get the following error:

> ./efbundle: relocation error: ./efbundle: symbol nanosleep version GLIBC_2.2.5 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time reference

However, if I move the `efbundle` file to the `publish` directory, everything seems to  work.

So my question is: Do I always have to put the `efbundle` file inside the `publish` folder? Or can I put it anywhere and apply the migrations to the database as it's a self-contained executable?

If not, what's the point of using the migrations bundle?

Comment: I am not sure but I suspect it requires your application DLL for the context. `--self-contained` removes the requirement of framework deployment normally if you want to provide a single file when you build you also need to provide another parameter like :`/p:PublishSingleFile=true` so you either need to copy it into publish folder or copy the required DLLs together.

Comment: I found the problem only occurs when installing the SDK with snap. Installing with APT works as expected. I think the problem is with snap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have installed the **DotNet SDK** on my Ubuntu machine with **snap**.
But after I reinstall it with **apt** it's now working from anywhere.
It seems that the problem is with the **snap** installation (I have also faced other EF issues before).
But still I am not sure if it's possible/how to fix the issue for a **snap** installation.